# Why validation fails when extracted into method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in process of writing my validation function in js.
When I have extracted logic into private method my validation fails. I cannot find out why.

My html defintion is:

```
<input type="text" id="searchQuery" data-minlenght="3">
```

This code should contain all validation logic for any element.

I am accessing all information using following lines:

```
  var query = jQuery("#searchQuery");
  cpodesign.Validation.isValid(query, query.val());
```

Now my validation implementation is

```
cpodesign.Validation = (function () {
            var Settings = {
                MinLenght: 'minlength',
            };

            //Private members

            function validateLenght(element, value) {
                var len = element.data(Settings.MinLenght);
                return (value.length > len);
            }

            return {
                // public members
                isValid: function (element, value) {
                    var marginRight = element.data(Settings.MinLenght);
                    if (marginRight !== 'undefined') {
                        return validateLenght(element, value); // does not work
                    }  

                    console.error('Validation type not defined');
                    return true;
                },
            };
        })();
```

This implementation works but I am not sure how to make the first work, as its what I would prefer.

```
 cpodesign.Validation = (function () {

            return {
                // public members
                isValid: function (element, value) {
                    var marginRight = element.data("minlenght");
                    if (marginRight !== 'undefined') {
                        return value.length > marginRight;
                    }

                    console.error('Validation type not defined');
                    return true;
                },
            };
        })();
```

Comment: You've spelled "length" incorrectly almost everywhere except in the property value here: `MinLenght: 'minlength'`. So when you say `element.data(Settings.MinLenght)` it won't find the `data-minlenght` attribute.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. cannot believe this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get an issue in IE with this hanging chad dangler

```
        var Settings = {
            MinLength: 'minlength',
        };
```

should be:

```
        var Settings = {
            MinLength: 'minlength'
        };
```

note: I also corrected the spelling of "MinLength"

Answer (score 1):

You have made a typo in your html. Should be:

> `<input type="text" id="searchQuery" data-minlength="3">`

instaid of:

> `<input type="text" id="searchQuery" data-minlenght="3">`

typo: `data-minlenght`